# Can a Cordova app be easily converted to the Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, migration, ionic2, cross-platform

I have a webapp that has been built using Cordova 2.x using Angular 1.3, I am considering moving this onto Ionic Cloud to take use of the online build/deployment features that this comes with, what are the issues faced with migrating an Cordova app to Ionic?